# How can you prevent users following your site?

Tags: permissions, search-results, newsfeed, following

I don't want a particular site being found by search, therefore stopping users without permission on that site from following it and seeing social feeds posted into there on their Newsfeed (which happens when you follow a site). I can hide the site from being searched, but that results in users in the site being unable to search for their own content.

Can't win?!

Comment: have you tried breaking permission and securing the site. this way search will only return results to users who has permission.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean Amal? The site is secured to just members and site owners I'm actually surprised it is showing up in search because I thought a users search only returned results from sites and libraries they have permissions to.

Comment: it is permission issue. i believe those users have read permission.

Comment: I'll double check the visitors and everyone groups to see what rights they have. Thanks

Comment: If you don't want the site found in search you can use Site Settings | Search and Offline Availability | Allow this site to appear in Search Results = No. From there use security to prevent access.

Comment: Thanks Mathew, but I still need the users to be able to search their Doclib and this breaks that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Site feeds**   Activities are publicly accessible unless the activity refers to content that **the user does not have access to.** If feed functionality is required for a restricted group of users, a site feed should be used. Site feeds display posts and replies among the users of the group. Site feed posts and **replies display in the Newsfeed of a user only if the user has access to the site feed. Site feeds do not display system-generated activities.** By default, the site feed feature on a team site is enabled. When you assign permissions to a team site that hosts a site feed, consider the following:

- Access to the site feed is restricted to the users specified in the
  permissions list.
- Users can post or reply only if they have the appropriate
  permissions.
- Security trimming is enforced. This means that no site feed
  activities will appear in the search results of a user who doesn't
  have access to the team site.
- Site feed activities appear in a user's Newsfeed if the user has
  access to the team site.
  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219700.aspx

So, this clearly tells, if user dont have the permission to site, even follow the site, but will not get the site feed activity. SO make sure user does not have permission...You can check from `Site setting> site permission and check user permissions.`

Answer (score 0):

There is a site feature called Following Content (Enable users to follow documents or sites.).

Does disabling this give you what you want?

Comment: Thanks Eric - yes and no. Gives the desired affect but I would like users with permissions to be able to follow the site so that they can get updates in their Newsfeed (unless being a member of the site automatically provides these updates anyway?)

Comment: what is the version is is SP online or SP 2013 on prem. you should post it to office 365 communities if its online.

Comment: It relates to OnPrem version of SharePoint

Answer (score 0):

Users who has minimum Read permissions will be able to see the results.

SharePoint security model uses permission inheritance. So top level permission get propagated to bottom levels.

So to tackle this you can remove permissions for those users. Or break permission inheritance and add only required users to the site.