# Temporary site unavailable setting in SPO except administrator

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, modern-experience, modern-team-site, maintenance

I use ModernUI in SharePoint Online.
Is it possible to temporarily disable the system for release work, site updates, etc., except for operational administrators?
I also want to prevent users who have registered their browser's favorite sites from directly accessing the URL.
It would be great if I can display message like "Site is under maintenance".

Appreciate any ideas\Pointers.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. It is not possible to disable the system for getting release from ‎Office 365‎, it is only supported to control [what release we may receive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?view=o365-worldwide). You will have to contact Microsoft for further control on your behalf.
2. You can set a site to Read Only using [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps):

   `Set-SPOSite -Identity <siteURL> -LockState ReadOnly`

   It will display a message on top of the site that it is under maintenance and read-only, but it will disable the activities on all users who have access, including Administrators. Also it doesn’t apply to the root site collection.

   As a workaround, I would suggest you restrict user access by adjusting user permissions directly.
3. We cannot prevent users from accessing a site via the URL (or following the site) as long as they have access to it. See a related post here: [How can you prevent users following your site?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142768/how-can-you-prevent-users-following-your-site)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand very well.
I have one question. If I set the site to ReadOnly with powershell, is it possible to update data with PowerAutomate without directly accessing SharePoint?

Comment: @Hyonta I’ve just ran a quick test using flow, and it returned an “Access is denied” error. So the answer is no, flow would not be possible either.

Comment: Thank you for investigating.It helps me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you think about the lockdown mode described on this site? Does this meet my requirements? https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/06/limited-access-user-permission-lockdown-mode-feature.html

Comment: @Hyonta I'm afraid not. The Limited-access user permission lockdown mode Feature is used to assign "Limited access" permission in a site. It will restrict but not disable user access under several circumstances. That would be a different topic.